# Labeling a loop arrow in state transition diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw a state transition diagram with tikz, but I am having trouble labeling an arrow loop. Here is what I've got so far:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, fit, calc}

\tikzset{
  ...
  state/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0.8em}
}

...

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance = 10em, >= triangle 45]
  \node[state] at (0,0) (closed) {1};
  \node[state] at (4,2) (opening) {2};

  \draw[->] (closed) -- (opening) node[midway, above left] {$1-a_1$};
  \draw[->] (closed) to [out=195, in=165, looseness=10] (closed);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: State transition diagram.]

It seems I have to use the `to` syntax for the looping arrow in order to be able to specify `out`, `in`, and `looseness`, but then I don't know how to label it. I want to put the label $a_1$ to the left of the looping arrow, and I would have thought something like what I used for the straight arrow would work, but that does not seem to be the case.

How can I label the looping arrow?

Comment: `\draw[->] (closed) to [out=195, in=165, looseness=10] node {$a_1$} (closed);` should work.

Comment: Oh wow, so the node command should go in between. This syntax seems to work well for the straight arrow as well. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, as a rule of thumb, the nodes along a path should always be between the path operation (or its options) and the target coordinate. Unless you define your own `to path` where `\tikztonodes` is not allowed to be there. The manual differentiates between [explicitly](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.8) and [implicitly](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.9) placed nodes.

Comment: Take also a look at the (always loaded) [`topaths` library](https://tikz.dev/library-edges) which defines things like `loop left` and the [`quotes` library](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.12.2) both allowing you to do `\draw[->] (closed) to[loop left, "$a_1$"] (closed);`.